# What do the highlighted patterns in the Apollo Flight Plan mean?

Tags: apollo-program

The [Apollo Flight Plan](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/us-history/apollo-11-flight-plan-180957225/) has distinctive patterns of markings (variously solid, broken, etc,) as well as other indicators (circular markings and the lines with labels such as CRO, MSFN, etc.).

[image]

[image]

What do these markings mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [copy](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11fltpln_final_reformat.pdf) of the flight plan has a cool decoder of all the symbology on page ix.  The pages immediately before this image have all the acronyms.

[image]

Comment: Doh! I looked through my copy dozens of times but couldn't find that, but there it is (on p. xi in the [original B&W version](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/apollo11/apollo-11-flight-plan-re-issue)).

Comment: @orome I'm glad you asked the question, I hadn't ever seen this annotated page myself.